# Switch themes when local storage changes onClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to switch themes between dark and light based on the theme key stored in the local storage. I have a function that changes the key value in the local storage on click. however, the click does not render the component and the user has to refresh the page to see the updated theme.

Here is the App.js component the check the local storage and set the default theme if null in local storage:

```
import React from  'react';


const App = () => {
  
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className=
                     {
                         window.localStorage.getItem('theme') === null ?
                             window.localStorage.setItem('theme','theme-light'):
                             window.localStorage.getItem('theme')
                     }>
                <Switch>
       
                    <Route exact path='/'> <LandingPage/> </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/register'> <RegisterPage/> </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/login'> <LoginPage/> </Route>
                    
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the function that contains a function to set the new theme in the local storage, onclick the key value does change in the local storage, however, the page does not re-render and requires the user to refresh the page manually to fetch the updated theme from local storage.

I want theme to switch on click.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {RiMoonLine} from 'react-icons/ri'
import {FiSun} from 'react-icons/fi'


const UserProfilePromoter = () =>{

    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    const items = { ...localStorage }
    const localUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'))

  useEffect(()=>{
      if(localUser){
          const userId = localUser.id
          const userFullName = `${localUser.firstname} ${localUser.lastname}`
          const username = localUser.username
          const avatar = localUser.avatar
          setUser({
              ...user,
              id: userId,
              name: userFullName,
              username: username,
              avatar: avatar,
              theme: items.theme
          })
      }

  },[])


    const onThemeChange = (e) => {
        let currentTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme')

        console.log(currentTheme)

        if(currentTheme === 'theme-light') {
            window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'theme-dark')
            setUser({
                ...user,
                theme: 'theme-dark'
            })
        } else {
            window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'theme-light')
            setUser({
                ...user,
                theme: 'theme-light'
            })
        }
    }

 

    return(
        <>
            {
                localUser &&
                <div className="profilePrompterContainer">
                    <div className="ProfilePrompterAvatarWrapper" role="button">
                        <div className="ProfilePrompterAvatar ProfilePrompterWrapper">
                            <img src={user.avatar}
                                 className="profilePrompterUserAvatar" alt={`sosums_user_${user.name}`}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="ProfilePrompterNameTag" role="button" >
                        <div className="userFullNameContainer">
                            <div className="userFullNameText">{user.name}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="profilePrompterUsernameText size12">
                            {!user.username ? <div className='setUserNameText'> @Set Username </div>: user.username}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="ProfilePrompterBtnGroup" onClick={onThemeChange}>
                        <button type="button" className="iconBtn">
                            <div className="iconContentWrapper">
                                <span className='iconContent'>
                                    {
                                        window.localStorage.getItem('theme')=== 'theme-light' ? <RiMoonLine/>:
                                            <FiSun/>
                                    }
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            }
            {
                !localUser && <div className="noLocalUser"> </div>
            }

        </>
    )
}

export default UserProfilePromoter
```

Comment: useeffect doesnot listen to change in localstorage

Comment: To re-render a React component you just need to update a state, but this time is different, to reload de app you have to force the reload with ```window.location.reload()```, this is same at user refrehs the page, you will need  find where use the reload()

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
As you wanted to rerender the parent `App` component, you need to send its update function to the child `UserProfilePromoter` component as props.

```
//Parent App component
export default function App() {
  const [themeUpdated, setThemeUpdated] = useState(false);

  const updateAppComponent = () => {
    setThemeUpdated(!themeUpdated);
  };

  const getClass = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem('theme');
  };

  return (
    <div className={getClass()}>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <Sample updateAppComponent={updateAppComponent} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//Child sample component
export default function Sample(props) {
  const { updateAppComponent } = props;
  const [themeToggle, setThemeToggle] = useState(false);

  const update = () => {
    setThemeToggle(!themeToggle);
    const themeName = themeToggle ? 'theme-red' : 'theme-blue';
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    updateAppComponent();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sample works!</h1>
      <button onClick={update}>Update</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: I used different component names and logic to update themes, but you will get the idea with the example.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sameer-react-av7fmm)

**Original**

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({})

useEffect(()=>{
  if(localUser){
      ...
  }

},[user]) //Add user state here
```

**Details**

`useEffect` first parameter is a method which gets executed **n** number of times based on 2nd parameter.

1. If you omit the 2nd param

```
useEffect(()=>{
 //this method gets invokes for every change in the component
})
```

2. If you add 2nd param as empty array(`[]`)

```
useEffect(()=>{
 //this method gets invoked exactly 1 time same as componentDidMount
})
```

3. If you add 2nd param as array(`[user]`) with user state

```
useEffect(()=>{
 //this method gets invoked when user state changes
})
```

Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZJgIjIuY7U&t=517s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified) or read this official [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: if I add the user as a 2nd parameter, it keeps re-rendering and throws an error: index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside effect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render. but the user state is only updated when user click on switch theme button.

Comment: @TayyabRahman I think you want to rerender `App` component right? because that's where you are applying a theme class